# Getting if-Statement error

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors

I've got a problem in **Keil uVision 4**. If I make a if-Statement with more than one condition, the compiler gives me an error message:

```
Build target 'HY-MiniSTM32V'
compiling main.c...
..\USER\main.c(28): error:  #29: expected an expression
..\USER\main.c(32): warning:  #12-D: parsing restarts here after previous syntax error
..\USER\main.c(32): error:  #65: expected a ";"
[...]
```

My "incorrect code" is this small snippet:

```
while(choosed != 1){
      getDisplayPoint(&display, Read_Ads7846(), &matrix);

      if(display.x <= 130) && (display.x >= 10) && (display.y <= 18) && (display.y >= 10){
          color = 0xF800;
          choosed = 1;
      }
}
```

Comment: That is not a problem with the Keil C compiler, it's a general syntax error problem in your code. Think again on how a condition in an `if` statement is supposed to be looking, especially in regards to parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the main braces of `if` statement. The compiler would treat your `if` statement as

```
(if(display.x <= 130)) && (display.x >= 10) && (display.y <= 18) && (display.y >= 10)
```

which gives you a syntax error. Change it to

```
if ((display.x <= 130) && (display.x >= 10) && (display.y <= 18) && (display.y >= 10))
```